# Change picture inside div(with borders) on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div and inside of div is icon from "Font Awesome". It is white background circle and inside circle yellow color icon. On hover circle change background color to yellow and icon inside of it changes color to white.

Now I need to change icon picture which is not in "Font awesome" library and need to make it stay in center and on hover of main div change colors.

Here is my solution which is not working right

```css
.imgBox {
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 191px;
  height: 191px;
  background: url(../images/greenhouse.png) no-repeat;
}

.imgBox:hover {
  width: 191px;
  height: 191px;
  background: url(../images/greenhouse2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="col-md-4 services-icon" onclick="parnik()">
    <div class="services-icon-info">
      <div class="imgBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-icon-text">
      <h4>Парники </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for class "services-icon-info"

```css
.services-icon-info {

 width: 80px;

    height: 80px;

    background: #FFFFFF;

    text-align: center;

    color: #FFC107;

    font-size: 2em;

    padding: .6em 0 0 0;

    border-radius: 50%;

 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

 -moz-border-radius: 50%;

 -ms-border-radius: 50%;

 -o-border-radius: 50%;

    margin: 0 auto;

 transition: 0.5s all;

 -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;

 -o-transition: 0.5s all;

 -moz-transition: 0.5s all;

 -ms-transition: 0.5s all;

}


.services-icon:hover div.services-icon-info {

background: #FFC107;

color: #FFFFFF;

}
```

[image]

This is how it works now( ignoring left side borders, I added 100px to each side, but it goes only down and right ) :
[image]

Comment: hm.. why do u have those 100 pixels padding? do you want to place it in center of the white circle? or do  you have another plan?

Comment: I added it from browser to see what happens if I try  to move it to left side and see that border start from up left side and not moving even if I force it and on change border increase only to down and right side

Answer (score 0):

One way for that is using a transparent PNG image

```
.image-icon{
    background-color:#fff; 
    border-radius:100px; // to make it circle
    margin:0 auto;       // to align it in center of container
    width:191px;
    height:191px;
    background: url(../images/greenhouse-white.png) no-repeat center center;  // white image icon 
}
.image-icon:hover{
    background-color:#f90;                                    // orange background color
    background-image:  url(../images/greenhouse-orange.png);  // orange image icon;
}
```

HTML can look like what you already have

```
<div class="services-icon-info">
  <div class="imgBox"></div>
  <h3>Title of box</h3>
</div>
```

See it in action here please :
https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/PjVoOM

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but unfortunately it did not work for me. If I delete width it goes to center bu cause of height it jump to down. If I remove width and change height to 32 px  it goes to required position, but hover is not working right(

Comment: Np :), I added a codepen,is this what you are looking for?

Comment: exactly, thank you) I will try to see what I can change to make it work!)

Comment: I added my CSS, maybe you can see mistake. I see problem that inserted image borders are not right. It increase to one side only and ignoring  left sides borders. I will attach picture in my question